# Matplotlib interpolating / plotting unstructured data

Tags: python, matplotlib

usually, Im working with image data which is in arrays the shape of m x n. Displaying is easy, right?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sample data
m,n = 10,20
sample = np.random.random((m,n))
plt.imshow(sample)
```

from a different algorith, Im now getting data which has x,y,data from a different shape as m,n but in the same range. Let me generate some sample to better explain.

```
k = 300
x = np.random.random((k,)) * m
y = np.random.random((k,)) * n
data = np.random.random((k,))
```

I want to do two things im not getting my head around.

1) Plotting the data in an imshow style

2) For better comparability, interpolate the data on a rectangular m,n grid, that is genrating an array of shape m,n with values from data (like "nearest").

Im actuallte using scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates to do the thing the way around but cant get it working inversed...

Cheers

Comment: I would split this into two questions. I think `interp2d` does what you want http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Comment: I would also suggest `interp2d`. Regarding your first question: you could always use `plt.pcolormesh(x, y, data)` to plot non-uniform data.

Comment: I couldn't get those to work. interp2d crashes with large data and wont produces a well conditioned function will small data. pcolormesh wont work with the inputs shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is slightly changed example of [scipy.interpolate.griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) usage:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 300
m, n = 10, 20

x = np.random.random((k,)) * m
y = np.random.random((k,)) * n
data = np.random.random((k,))

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:m+1, 0:n+1]

grid_z0 = griddata((x, y), data, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
grid_z1 = griddata((x, y), data, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
grid_z2 = griddata((x, y), data, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(grid_z0.T)
plt.title('Nearest')

plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(grid_z1.T)
plt.title('Linear')

plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(grid_z2.T)
plt.title('Cubic')

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 6)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, perfect! Only cubic is giving me some interesting "rays" in areas of large gradients, but thats my data most certainly. Linear is perfect and still fast with 1e6 data points